# how to alert when audit failure occurs?

Tags: auditing

I have a security requirement about alerting when a fail occurs on audit event, I mean I have to know when Sharepoint audit fails and alert key personnel. do you know how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information would come from the specific server's Security Event Log.

You need to enable auditing via Group Policy, then you can track the events listed here: [Audit logon events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/auditing/basic-audit-logon-events)

Comment: You are right when you say that I have to track events, but I don't want to audit logons but when Audit process on Sharepoint fails.